# Шаблон в качестве параметра шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как правильно передавать шаблон в качестве параметра другому шаблону?

```
template < typename T >
struct A{};

template < template < typename > class C >
struct B{}; 

typedef A < int > A_int;
typedef A < float > A_float;

typedef B < A_float > B_A_float; // error C3200: 'A_float' : invalid template argument for template parameter 'C', expected a class template
typedef B < A < float > > B_A_float; // error C3200: 'A<T>' : invalid template argument for template parameter 'C', expected a class template
typedef B < A > B_A_float; // компилируется но бесполезно
```

необходимо использовать в шаблоне разные специализации шаблона, но компилятор позволяет вставить только сам класс

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если Вы хотите просто передать шаблону какой-то тип, то в качестве параметра шаблона надо использовать параметр-тип:

```
template<class X> struct foo { X x; };
//       ^ параметр-тип.       ^ используется как тип.

foo<int> obj;         // ОК, передали тип int, получили поле "int x;"
foo<vector<int>> obj; // ОК, передали тип vector<int>, получили поле "vector<int> x;"
foo<vector>           // не ок. "vector x;" не компилируется
```

А если же надо передать шаблону *шаблон*, то параметром должен быть параметр-шаблон:

```
template<template<class> class X> struct foo { X<int> x; };
//       ^ параметр-шаблон.                    ^ используется как шаблон.

foo<vector> obj;      // ОК, передали шаблон vector<T>, получилось поле "vector<int> x;"
foo<int> obj;         // не ок. "int<int> x;" не компилируется
foo<vector<int>> obj; // не ок. "vector<int><int> x;" не компилируется
```

Comment: А что можно сделать [в случае с функцией](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/585212/178988)?

Comment: @Qwertiy то же самое.

Answer (score 3):

Согласно C++ стандарту (14.3.3 Template template arguments)

> 1 A template-argument for a template template-parameter shall be **the
>   name of a class template or an alias template**, expressed as
>   id-expression. When the template-argument names a class template, only
>   primary class templates are considered when matching the template
>   template argument with the corresponding parameter; partial
>   specializations are not considered even if their parameter lists match
>   that of the template template parameter.

Вы же пытаетесь в качестве шаблонного аргумента использовать аргумент тип, и, естественно, компилятор выдает сообщение об ошибке.

То есть вы не передаете в качестве аргументов шаблоны, а передаете конкретные типы такие, как, например, `A<int>` или `A<float>`

Простой пример использования шаблонного параметра шаблона:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct A { T x; };

template <class T, template <class> class C = A>
struct B 
{
    C<T> c;
};

int main()
{
    B<int> b1 = { { 10 } };
    B<float> b2 = { { 20.20 } };

    std::cout << b1.c.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << b2.c.x << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
10
20.2
```